# Multithreading shell for loop with find with filenames containing spaces

Tags: multithreading, shell

I write a shell script to simulate multithreading like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROCESS_NUM=5
FIFO=/tmp/$$.fifo

mkfifo $FIFO
exec 3<>$FIFO
for i in $(seq 1 $PROCESS_NUM); do
    echo $i>&3
done

echo "= start ="
for i in $(find "$1" -iname "*.jpg")
do
    read -u3 p
    {
        md5sum "$i"
        echo $p>&3
    } &
done
wait

exec 3>&-
rm $FIFO
echo "= end ="
```

It was ok and output like this:

```
= start =
2f6add89a29b1315166255c41899744b ./img.jpg
...
...
...
= end =
```

But when the file path contenting spaces, it was error and output like this:

```
= start =
md5sum: ./my: No such file or directory
md5sum: img.jpg: No such file or directory
...
...
...
= end =
```

so I change the loop like this:

```
find "$1" -iname "*.jpg"|while read i
do
    read -u3 p
    {
        md5sum "$i"
        echo $p>&3
    } &
done
```

It was ok but it would not wait for background process finsh:

```
= start =
...
...
= end =
2f6add89a29b1315166255c41899744b ./my img.jpg
...
```

How should I solve the problem?

Comment: BashPitfalls #1: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: ...waitaminute. You've already solved the problem with spaces, so why's that still part of your title and half of your question? Feels like I just wasted a lot of time reading through things you already fixed.

Comment: Note the "minimal" part of MVCE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...also, not all multiprocessing is multithreading. Subshells as background processes are just that -- processes -- not threads, which (always) share memory space and (typically) have different scheduling treatment

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry, maybe my description is not clear。I solved the problem with spaces, but it appear a new probleam. the script would calculate md5 in background, and it should wait for all background processes finsh and then output `= end =`, but when I replace the loop with `while`, the script would not wait the background process finish.

Comment: If you solved the problem with spaces, why do you still talk about it in your question at all? My objection is the rambling, more than anything else. Questions should contain **minimal** code examples -- enough to reproduce the exact and immediate problem you ask about, and nothing more. Spaces are a solved issue, so there's no need to mention them anywhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my point is: when I use `for` loop, then script could wait the background process, but it could not solved the probleam with spaces. when I use `while` loop, it could solved the probleam with spaces, but it could not wait the background process finsh. So I wanted a solution to fix two problem at the same time

Comment: Well -- if you want to know how to use a `for` loop correctly (which you weren't), that's a different question, and it's one that can be answered.

Comment: ...as the BashPitfalls link I gave you at the very start of this comment thread says, `for x in $(...)` is never the right thing for filenames.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your suggestion, I would learn more about the bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job control isn't intended for noninteractive use -- for that matter, the job table is of a very limited size and discards content when it overflows.

Collect the PIDs, and wait for them individually.

```
pids=( )
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  { your_stuff_here; } &
  pids+=( "$?" )
done < <(find "$1" -iname '*.jpg' -print0)

for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do wait "$pid"; done
```

Note the use of `IFS='' read -r -d ''` and `find -print0` -- otherwise, you'd have a bad day with filenames containing backslash escape sequences or newlines (both which are, yes, entirely valid on POSIX filesystems).

Answer (score 1):

If you're convinced that other issues can be fixed by using a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop, this is straightforwardly done: Use a `while` loop to read NUL-delimited results from `find` into an array, then iterate over the array's contents with a `for` loop.

```
contents=( )
while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename; do
  contents+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find "$1" -iname '*.jpg' -print0)

for filename in "${contents[@]}"; do
  ...
done
```